# Image does not uploaded in vue-codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, vue.js

I build an app use vue and codeigniter rest server, I try to upload file by postman and it's work fine, but when I try from front-end, file is not uploaded, folder permission has been allowed, this is my vue code

```
data() {
   return {
      data: {
         photo: // base64 data
      }
   }
}
```

on methods

```
addMember(){
   this.axios.post('member', this.data).then(res => {
      console.log(res)
   }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
   })
}
```

on back end

```
$filename = round(microtime(true)).'.png';
$config['file_name']            = $filename;
$config['upload_path']          = './storage/';
$config['allowed_types']        = '*';
$config['max_size']             = 50000;
$config['max_width']            = 50000;
$config['max_height']           = 50000;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->do_upload('photo');
```

thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

I think if you success get the send but without file, maybe your send type has error
For server Base64 is a String ,not a file(byte stream) ,for axios ,default send type is Application/json, and it only can not send a Byte Stream , so you should cheack your server can get a String and transform to file
But if your server want a file , you should use formData
And I suggest you use FormData to send file
Here is a examples for you if you want use axios send formData.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append(photo,this.photo);
this.$axios({
  url: '/member',
  method: 'post',
  data: formData
});
```